# How to combine get only the numbers from a list

Tags: haskell

I've got this code here:

```
-- Types
type Title = String
type Director = String
type Year = Int
type Rating = (String, Int)

-- Define Film type here
type Film = (Title, Director, Year, [Rating])


-- Define database type here
type Database = [Film]

testDatabase :: [Film]
testDatabase = [("Casino Royale", "Martin Campbell", 2006, 
  [("Garry",-8),("Dave", 0)]), ("Blade Runner", "Ridley Scott", 1982, 
  [("Amy",5)]), ("The Fly", "David Cronenberg", 1986, [("Fred",7)])]

displayFilmsuser :: String -> Database -> String
displayFilmsuser user database = displayuserFilms (filter (isuser user) database) 


isuser:: String -> Film -> Bool
isuser user (t,d,y,r)
 |    length  (filter ((== user).fst) r) > 0 = True
 | otherwise = False    

displayuserFilm ::  Film -> String 
displayuserFilm  (title, director, year, rating)  = "\nTitle: " ++ title ++  "\nRating: " ++ show  (filter ((== user).fst) rating) ++ "\n"

displayuserFilms :: Database -> String
displayuserFilms database  = concat(map displayuserFilm database )
```

How can I combine those function and get an outpu like:

Title: Casine Royale
Rating: 4

I can get an output like:
Title: Casino Royal
Rating:  [("Garry",-8),("Dave", 0)]

I need when i give as input to the function displayFilmsuser "Garry" testDatabase
to get the Film's title that the user has rated and the rate that the user rated.
Im really lost in there. Could you give some clues please?

Comment: The [`lookup`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=a+-%3E+%5B%28a%2C+b%29%5D+-%3E+Maybe+b) function takes a `String` and your list of `Rating`s and will give you a `Maybe Int`.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, did misunderstand you.

Then I would implement it, like @kqr suggested, via `lookup`:

```
displayUserRating :: String -> Film -> (String, Maybe Int)
displayUserRating s (t,d,y,rs) = (t, lookup s rs)
```

This yields for your first film:

`displayUserRating "Garry" (head testDatabase)`

`=("Casino Royale", Just (-8))`

The `Maybe` is good to have here, because with it, you can identify, whether the user has rated, or not. 
For the other films, it would get `(FilmTitle, Nothing)` (Garry didn't rate any other films)

For the whole Database:

```
displayUserRatings :: String -> Database -> [(Title,Int)]
displayUserRatings s d = let ratings = map (displayUserRating s) d 
                         in [(t,fromJust r) | (t,r) <- ratings, r /=Nothing]
                         where
                            fromJust (Just a) = a
```

Here you get only those films, which were actually rated by s ("Garry"), if not, they're filtered out (via `r /= Nothing`). Therefore, it is safe to use the function `fromJust`, because we know, that r has to be a `Just Int`

Comment: Thanks Kaan for your reply, but I dont really need to get the average ratings of the films. I need to give as input the username ("Garry") and testDatabase. So this function will search the database if Garry has rated any films, it will output the film title and the rate that Garry rated. Thanks again

Comment: Ah sorry, thought, you have 2 tasks. I corrected my answer